# Complex tests - dependency on same test data

Tags: c#, .net, testing

I'm developing custom serializer as hobby project and I would like learn the TDD on it.

I have a tests for serialization & deserialization simple object graphs.
Now I want test some complex graphs with non-trivial deserialization (i.e. classes with no parameterless constructor, cyclic references, large amount of objects, etc ...).

I need test the "building" and "extracting" graph of serialization and I need test the serialization & deserialization of created graph. I would like test all four actions with several graph (from simple over complex to super-complex graphs).

Should I create some non-Test class providing the predefined graphs for all tests or every test should have own source of graphs?

I'm asking this question because I see possible problem with dependecny several tests on one clas (the provider of graphs).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not necessarily a "right" answer here; it depends on your project and your tests.  It *seems* to be a good idea to have a common source of graphs - not necessarily a single class but maybe a set of classes (i.e. a graph factory/repository) that could generate graphs representing different concepts (the class lacking parameterless constructor, cyclic references etc).

This doesn't avoid the risk of having multiple tests relying on a common source but you need to weigh that against the cost of defining the construction of each graph.  You could end up with a lot of duplicated code across tests.  If there is benefit to re-using a given graph definition; the graph factory may be the way forward.

One idea may be to have a meta-test/set of meta-tests against each graph so that you can confirm the graph validity.  The point being that if a set of actual tests that all consume the same graph are suddenly failing you look to the meta-tests first and ensure that they are passing.  The tests that you are planning should each be focussing on a single aspect (build/extract etc) and those tests can then rely on the graph validity.

The key thing is to keep each test as simple as possible so that if/when it fails its obvious *why* its failing - by having graph construction elsewhere (and separately validating it) you can have your serialization tests focussing on that and that alone.